# How to set coordinates to the xml of the kml file?

Tags: android, xml, kml

I have a code that creates a kml file with some informations. When im passing this informations i pass too the latitude, longitude and altitude to my object, and then, the method object.setCoordinates(coordinate) catch the lat., long. and alt. from my object, but when i try to open my file in Google Earth, it opens in the middle of the ocean, because in the xml, the coordinates are 0.0, 0.0 , 0.0 .
Can someone help me? I look at the code and dont see any problems or mistakes.

Comment: I found the problem. :]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there must be some missing data set as zeros in your original source, or an error in the way you are transferring it.

I think we need a little more information.

Bob J.

By the way lat=0 and Long = 0 is a place off the coast of Nigeria